# is there already a function similar to this in any C lib?

Tags: c, arrays, function, slide

I've been stalking this place for a while but this is my first post so please be indulgent.
I've coded this function for a school project, but don't know how to name it (we have to make our own functions). Question is, does anyone know if there's a similar function in a library, just so I know how to name it ?

```
void function(char *str, int slen)
{
    while(*str) {
        if (slen) {
            *str = *(str + slen);
        } else {
            *str = '\0';
        }

        if (*(str + slen) == '\0') {
            slen = 0;
        }

        str++;
    }
}
```

What it does:

Slide an string by `SLEN` chars towards the beginning, filling the end with `'\0'`.
Example :

```
char *str = strdup("I want to remove 8 characters");
function(str, 8);
```

turns my string into `"remove 8 characters.\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`

Comment: uhm, what is this function supposed to do/

Comment: Edited to make it clearer =)

Comment: This looks dangerous. What if you put `slen` quite large? You can skip over the `\0` from the `str`.

Comment: Uhm, typically such a function is not needed, if you want to pass a string skipping the first `n` character you just do `str+n`.

Comment: So it's a function which removes the last N characters? Well, there you have the name: `remove_last_n`.

Comment: The example code produces undefined behavior, you can't modify a string initialized by a literal like that.

Comment: unwind : Yeah I know, I just wanted to give an example, I actually use it to manipulate buffers filled with read().


luk32 : I use it to manipulate buffers filled via read() so they're hardly ever null-terminated anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `memcpy` (or `memmove` if the `from` and `to` areas overlap)

and then `memset`

There is no one function that does both

Comment: memcpy can't be used when source and buffer destinations overlap. Use `memmove`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass it to a function that wouldn't be responsible for cleaning the memory later you can just give that function `str+len`:

```
printFunc(str+len);
```

but if you need to pass this string on without the first `len` `chars` so you can `memcpy` the string onto a new string and free the last one.